Populating tree view to audit a formula
I have been trying to develop a code to develop a formula audit tool. What I want to achieve is that when I run the macro, it copies the formula to the major node and then evaluates the parts of the formula in child nodes. If there are nested formula, I want it to evaluate further using additional child nodes by branching methodology.
Has someone thought of this?
I have been working on the code which looks like this -
' Declare a global variable for TreeView node count
Dim treeNodeCount As Integer

' Main subroutine to initiate auditing and populate TreeView
Sub AuditAndPopulateTreeView()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim formula As String
    Dim rootNode As Node

    ' Clear existing TreeView nodes
    ClearTreeView

    ' Get the currently selected cell
    Set rng = Selection
    formula = rng.formula

    ' Add root node to TreeView
    Set rootNode = UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(, , "Root", "Formula in selected cell: " & formula)
    rootNode.Expanded = True

    ' Audit formula components and populate TreeView
    treeNodeCount = 0
    PopulateTreeView rootNode, rng, formula

    ' Show the UserForm with the populated TreeView
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

' Function to recursively populate TreeView with formula components
Sub PopulateTreeView(parentNode As Node, rng As Range, formula As String)
    Dim components() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim newNode As Node

    ' Split formula into components (operators, functions, references, etc.)
    components = SplitFormula(formula)

    ' Evaluate each component
    For i = LBound(components) To UBound(components)
        ' Create a new node in TreeView for the component
        treeNodeCount = treeNodeCount + 1
        Set newNode = UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parentNode.Index, tvwChild, "Node" & treeNodeCount, components(i))

        ' Evaluate component and its dependencies
        EvaluateAndPopulateNode newNode, rng, components(i)
    Next i
End Sub

' Function to evaluate component and populate TreeView accordingly
Sub EvaluateAndPopulateNode(currentNode As Node, rng As Range, component As String)
    Dim referencedRange As Range
    Dim subFormula As String

    ' Example evaluation logic for each component
    Select Case True
        Case IsNumeric(component) ' If component is a number
            currentNode.Text = currentNode.Text & " (Constant)"

        Case Left(component, 1) = "=" ' If component is a formula reference
            On Error Resume Next
            Set referencedRange = Range(Mid(component, 2))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not referencedRange Is Nothing Then
                currentNode.Text = currentNode.Text & " (Reference: " & referencedRange.Address & ")"
                ' Highlight referenced range cells
                referencedRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' Yellow highlight

                ' Recursively evaluate the referenced range's formula
                subFormula = referencedRange.formula
                If subFormula <> "" Then
                    PopulateTreeView currentNode, referencedRange, subFormula
                End If
            Else
                currentNode.Text = currentNode.Text & " (Invalid Reference)"
            End If

        Case InStr(component, "(") > 0 ' If component is a function
            currentNode.Text = currentNode.Text & " (Function)"

            ' Extract the arguments of the function and evaluate them
            Dim args As String
            args = Mid(component, InStr(component, "(") + 1, Len(component) - InStr(component, "(") - 1)
            subFormula = Replace(args, ",", " ") ' Replace commas with spaces for splitting

            ' Recursively evaluate the function arguments
            If subFormula <> "" Then
                PopulateTreeView currentNode, rng, subFormula
            End If

        Case Else ' For other cases (operators, etc.)
            currentNode.Text = currentNode.Text & " (Operator or Other)"
    End Select

    ' Highlight evaluated component in TreeView node
    currentNode.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 255) ' Blue text color
End Sub

' Function to split formula into components
Function SplitFormula(formula As String) As String()
    Dim components() As String

    ' Split formula by spaces (considering spaces as delimiters)
    components = Split(formula, " ")

    ' Return array of formula components
    SplitFormula = components
End Function

' Subroutine to clear TreeView nodes
Sub ClearTreeView()
    ' Clear all nodes in TreeView
    UserForm1.TreeView1.Nodes.Clear
End Sub

Please help me fix the error if possible!!

Which error? - Please be more specific.

Has someone thought of this?  Maybe have a look at the advanced formula environment in Excel Labs?
